# Solving csv files with quoted semicolon in Pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, data-cleaning, quoting

So I am facing the following problem:

I have a `;` separated csv, which has `;` enclosed in quotes, which is corrupting the data.

So like `abide;acdet;"adds;dsss";acde`

The `;` in the `"adds;dsss"` is moving `" dsss"` to the next line, and corrupting the results of the ETL module which I am writing. my ETL is taking such a csv from the internet, then transforming it (by first loading it in Pandas data frame, doing pre-processing and then saving it), then loading it in sql server. But corrupted files are breaking the sql server schema.

Is there any solution which I can use in conjunction with Pandas data frame which allows me to fix this issue either during the read(pd.read_csv) or writing(pd.to_csv)( or both) part using Pandas dataframe?

Comment: Please share your existing code. It's hard to understand your problem otherwise.

Comment: You mean "quoted semicolon" not comma. If CSV export did that, it's because the semicolon character was actually part of that field. Turn on quoting in read_csv. But for less grief in general and to make your CSV file processable with Gnu awk, grep etc. you might like to use PSV (pipe-separated value, '|')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to tell the reader some fields may be quoted:

```
pd.read_csv(your_data, sep=';', quotechar='"')
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = StringIO("""abide;acdet;"adds;dsss";acde""")
df = pd.read_csv(txt,sep=';',header=None)
print(df)
```

Output dataframe:

```
       0      1          2     3
0  abide  acdet  adds;dsss  acde
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sep` parameter of `pd.read_csv` allows you to specify which character is used as a separator in your CSV file. Its default value is `,`. Does changing it to `;` solve your problem?